# Fatal Exception, : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, exception, null

here is the exception:

```
    Attempt to invoke virtual method
android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder
android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(int)' on a
null object reference
```

I have put ----> arrow to the lines of code that seem to have lead to the exception, this exception occurs when i press record on the app

If you need more information please just ask, i will post all relevant information, I am trying to get the hang of android development all help is appreciated!!!

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera2_video_image2);

    createVideoFolder();

    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    mRecordImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.videoOnlineImageButton);
    mRecordImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           if(mIsRecording){
               mIsRecording = false;
               mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.btn_video_online);
               //stop recording then restart preview
               mMediaRecorder.stop();
               mMediaRecorder.reset();
               startPreview();
           }else{
           ------>    checkWriteStoragePermission();
               mIsRecording = true;
               mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.btn_video_busy);

           }
       }
    });
}

    private void checkWriteStoragePermission() {
    //check if it is Marshmallow build
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            mIsRecording = true;
            mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.btn_video_busy);
            try{
                createVideoFileName();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          ------>  startRecord();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        }else{
            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                Toast.makeText(this,"app needs to able to save videos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);

        }
    }else{
        mIsRecording = true;
        mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.btn_video_busy);
        try{
            createVideoFileName();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startRecord();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
}

    private void startRecord(){

    try {
        setupMediaRecorder();
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        try
    ---->    {mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            try {
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),null,null);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

                        }
                    }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.tadewos.myapplication, PID: 8049
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.tadewos.myapplication.Camera2VideoImageActivity2.startRecord(Camera2VideoImageActivity2.java:309)
                                                                                 at com.example.tadewos.myapplication.Camera2VideoImageActivity2.checkWriteStoragePermission(Camera2VideoImageActivity2.java:450)
                                                                                 at com.example.tadewos.myapplication.Camera2VideoImageActivity2.access$900(Camera2VideoImageActivity2.java:48)
                                                                                 at com.example.tadewos.myapplication.Camera2VideoImageActivity2$3.onClick(Camera2VideoImageActivity2.java:165)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22624)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is where i declare Cameradevice:

```
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener(){

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        setupCamera(width, height);
        connectCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }
};


private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice = camera;
        if(mIsRecording){
            try {
                createVideoFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startRecord();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        }else{
        startPreview();}
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                    "Camera connection made!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        camera.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        camera.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Those lines can't (directly) throw a NPE. Post your full stack trace.

Comment: How/where do you assign `mCameraDevice` ?

Comment: I dont see mCameraDevice assigned a value.. that is the reason `createCaptureRequest ` throws null pointer exception..

Comment: i have added where i assign mCameraDevice and stacktrace

Comment: Where do you register the StateCallback? onOpened is never called and mCameraDevice is always null.